# HiveConf of name hive.files.umask.value does not exist

Tags: hive

When I executed a sql script. I got the tilt data problem, so I tried to set `hive.groupby.shewindata` parameter to optimize it as below

> set hive.groupby.shewindata=true;
>   my hql scripy here ...

**Hive Version: V2.0.0**

**Hadoop version: V2.4.0**

when I tried, I got the following error:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/www/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/www/spark-sql-hzsearch/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/www/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/www/spark-sql-hzsearch/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   2016-12-28 21:07:10,902 WARN  [main] conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(2753)) - HiveConf of name hive.files.umask.value does not exist
>
> Logging initialized using configuration in 
>       jar:file:/home/www/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>       OK
>        Time taken: 0.502 seconds Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: hive configuration hive.groupby.shewindata does not exists.

Any ideas why this error came out?

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence is:

```
set hive.groupby.skewindata= true;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties